# Saving to Django ImageField

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using jcrop to crop and image that I would then like to save to an ImageField.

I've successfully saved to an ImageField in other sections of my site with the code below but in this instance I get the following error message:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

**My View**

```
def archive_update_profile_photo(request, id, slug):

    photo_to_crop_from= Media.objects.get(id=2)

    form = CropForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CropForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            x = form.cleaned_data['x']
            y = form.cleaned_data['y']
            w = form.cleaned_data['w']
            h = form.cleaned_data['h']
            print x, y, w, h

            selected_media= Media.objects.get(id=2)

            raw_image = Image.open(selected_media.diplay_photo)

            # crop here
            l = x
            t = y
            r = x + w
            b = y + h
            cropped_image = raw_image.crop((l, t, r, b))

            # resize here
            profile_image = cropped_image.resize((150, 150), Image.ANTIALIAS)


            profile_image.show()

            legacy = Legacy.objects.get(id=id)

            #save the profile image
            temp_handle = StringIO()
            profile_image.save(temp_handle, 'jpeg')
            temp_handle.seek(0)
            #save  profile image to imagefield
            suf = SimpleUploadedFile(os.path.split(legacy.legacy_profile_image.name)[-1].split('.')[0], temp_handle.read(), content_type='image/jpeg')
            legacy.legacy_profile_image.save('%s.jpg' % suf.name, suf, save=True)

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('archive_legacy', args=(id,slug)))

    return render(request, 'archive_app/archive_update_profile_photo.html', {'form': form,'photo_to_crop_from':photo_to_crop_from})
```

**My Model**

```
def get_legacy_profile_image_name(request, instance):
    return 'profile_images/%s__%s' % (str(time()).replace('.','-'), 'legacy_profile_image')

class Legacy(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    legacy_profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_legacy_profile_image_name, blank=True, null=True)
```

**Trackback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/archive/update/profile/image/5/Virginia-Meeks/

Django Version: 1.5.4
Python Version: 2.7.1
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'bootstrap_toolkit',
 'longerusername',
 'south',
 'storages',
 'boto',
 'archive')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/bbrooke/Code/yourlegacy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/bbrooke/Code/yourlegacy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  25.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/bbrooke/Code/yourlegacy/archive/views.py" in archive_update_profile_photo
  500.          suf = SimpleUploadedFile(os.path.split(legacy.legacy_profile_image.name)[-1].split('.')[0], temp_handle.read(), content_type='image/jpeg')
File "/Users/bbrooke/Code/yourlegacy/env/bin/../lib/python2.7/posixpath.py" in split
  83.     i = p.rfind('/') + 1

Exception Type: AttributeError at /archive/update/profile/image/5/Virginia-Meeks/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

I really appreciate your the feedback and expertise

Comment: Please post the traceback

Comment: sk1p I just added the Traceback. I appreciate any thoughts you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`legacy.legacy_profile_image.name` is `None`. This may happen, because `legacy_profile_image` is nullable. So, you might want to add a `None` check there.

Also, your `upload_to` method `get_legacy_profile_image_name` is kind of broken; the arguments passed are [`instance` and `filename`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to), not `request` and `instance`. It doesn't really matter, because you don't use the arguments…

Comment: perfect! I removed "null=True" from my field and it works great. Thanks for the help.